# Initializing a SAFEARRAY ref in C# (port from VB?)

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, ref, safearray

I am working with a third-party COM component (i.e. do not have its code). The method in question has the following outline:

```
HRESULT GetTableInfo(  
[in] BSTR bstrTableName, 
[in,out] SAFEARRAY(BSTR) bstrColumnTitles, 
[in,out] SAFEARRAY(long) lColumnPos );
```

I have tried to pass a ref to a fixed-size array ((Array)string[6]) and to a List.ToArray(), but it keeps crashing on me. E.g.

```
Array arr1 = (Array) new string[500];
Array arr2 = (Array) new int[500];
table.GetTableInfo(filename, ref arr1, ref arr2);
```

To be more specific: I already tried any value for the size (the correct one should be 44). Tried the same for the capacity of a List<>, but that didn't help either. I also tried different types, but it does not accept any other than int.

I don't know why it keeps crashing on me with a general error of that COM component (basically indicating that something is wrong, yet not saying what exactly), since I can confirm that the following VB code works:

```
Dim TitleList() As String
Dim PositionList() As Long 
Call objTable.GetTableInfo(txTableFile.Text, TitleList, PositionList)
```

Does anyone have a clue on why this happens? Or alternatively, can anyone provide me a port of that VB code to C#? I have tried to google for tutorials, but all they say is "only fixed size arrays are allowed". I wonder how that code works then, as no size is specified.

Thx i.a.

Comment: `SAFEARRAY` isn't just a normal array. It's this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You are not passing the same types compared to your VB and C# code. The VB seems to be passing a `string[]` and `long[]` as parameters, while your C# code seems to be passing a `string[]` and `int[]` parameters, respectively. Try passing the correct parameters and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Polynomial: So do I have to manually build that struct and cast the ref param to that struct type?

Comment: @FranzB. - Yeah, it's quite likely that you'll have to do that.

Comment: @Tejs: See above. I tried to use other types such as long, but then it tells me during runtime that a wrong type was specified. Only int seems to work.

Comment: @Polynomial Thats not true - the .Net interop layer handles marshalling to and from Safe arrays for you

Comment: @Justin - Thanks for the clarification. Wasn't aware that p/invoke marshalled it automatically.

Comment: Additionally, such a custom struct as ref param leaves me with an "invalid argument" message, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [Default Marshaling for Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?  As far as I can tell this should "just work" as long as you use the `MarshalAs` attribute on the PInvoke declaration to indicate that the array should be marshalled as a safe array.

As far as I can tell the correct PInvoke declaration should be something along the lines

```
public static string extern GetTableInfo(
    string tableName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_BSTR)]
    ref string[] columnTitles,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_I8)]
    ref long[] columnPos
);
```

Can you show us what your PInvoke declaration looks like?

Comment: I wish it would just work :) I am not sure where to get the PInvoke declaration you are referring to. The only thing I can see is the signature of the method in the object browser of Visual Studio. That one just says... $ GetTableInfo(string, ref System.Array, ref System.Array) $

Comment: @FranzB. Thats the PInvoke declaration I was talking about - try modifying it to match the one I have shown.

Comment: I do not know how to modify it. It is included in a third-party COM component of which I do not have the code. If there is an option to alter that declaration, where can I find it?

Comment: That's the C# declaration in your code (or interop generated code) so that C# knows how to call the 3rd party COM component.

Comment: Looks like I should really find that easily, yet I have a hard time grasping what you mean. I included the COM component as a Reference into the project and can access its classes and methods like any other package (such as System.Collections). How would I be able to find that generated code?

Comment: @FranzB. If its generated then you can't change it, but it also shouldn't be wrong! This same reference works perfectly in the VB project?  If so try just changing the second array type to `long[]` to see if that helps as Tejs suggested in comments.  If that doesn't work you will probably need to get in touch with the people who supplied the COM interop library.

Comment: I tried to include the code above into my main class file, but the linker tells me it cannot find that entry point in the DLL. I guess that happens because GetTableInfo is a method of class CTable which has to be instantiated by a call to GetInterface(SomeEnum.TABLE) first, in order to use that method.

Comment: Yes, the VB code above works perfectly. My guess is that this is due to the dynamic array in VB or due to the type. Whenever I use long[], it complains about a wrong type. I am still waiting for the reply of the COM lib supplier. They probably also try to figure out where things go wrong and may blame it on C#... which would leave me stranded with the same question as above. At the moment, I have emulated the method manually, but that is an ugly and dangerous workaround.

Comment: I finally solved it. The key to the solution was Array.CreateInstance(). Even though it took me ages to find the last error, I still mark this as the solution since you pointed me in the right direction.